# How to migrate Drupal Commerce configuration between environments

Tags: 7, commerce, features

I'd normally use [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to migrate changes from a dev server to a live one, however it seems [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) doesn't fully support features, which leaves me in a tight spot.

How would you suggest to migrate the changes over without causing disruption? The live site is updated constantly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Commerce Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_features) has helped me in the past.

Apart from that, you're looking at update hooks (or possibly the [Configuration Management](https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) module).

Comment: I didn't know about Commerce features. I'll give it a try. Thanks!